# What kind of timings consider by nanoTime method?

Tags: java

I have written a java code and use the Scanner class to get the value from the user and  System.nanoTime at the begin and end to get the total time of my code. Is it considering the time while I typing the input?

Comment: Yes. It also considers all other OS functions between those two lines of time-getting code.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Yes think it like a normal clock. Whenever you printed Nanotime, it shows that current time in Nanoseconds type.